# SQL Flask methods objects in same thread

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask

SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test/")

def test():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("god_attributes.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM god_icon_table")
    all = c.fetchall()

return render_template("test.html", all = all)
```

I'm making a flask app and I have a lot of methods that need to pull data from a db using SQL db calls. I am wondering if I can store methods somewhere else and call them by importing to organize things. Basically I want the entire app route for test to be like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test/")
def test():
    all = get_all()
    return render_template("test.html", all = all)
```

where get_all() does everything from conn to fetchall in the first code sample

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a structural solution. Wasnt able to place a get_all() method that does the SQL commands directly. I made a new json file from the database and used that json to get the information